# ¿Cómo imprimo una excepción en PHP?

Tags: php, excepciones, try-catch

Normalmente en **java** u otro lenguaje similar suelo utilizar un try-catch para luego imprimir el stacktrace.

Se puede utilizar un try-catch en php?

Comment: Si buscas en la documentación de PHP, encontrarás que sí: [PHP: Excepciones](http://php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php)

Answer (score 3):

He encontrado que se puede utilizar `try-catch` en `php` de igual forma que en java u otros lenguajes similares

```
<?php
//ejemplo de funcion con excepcion
function chequearNumero($numero) {
  if($numero>1) {
    throw new Exception("Valor debe ser 1 o menor");
  }
  return true;
}

//lanzar excepcion de prueba
chequearNumero(2);
?>
```